# Find the index of the first occurrence of some value that is not X or Y in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector of the following form:

```
import numpy as np
vec = np.array([2, 2, 2, 51, 51, 52, 52, 14, 14, 14, 51, 51, 52, 52])
```

Is there a numpy-thonic way to find the index of the *first occurrence* of a value that is *not* (for instance) 51 or 52? In other words, a function that would return the following indexes: [0, 7], where 0 is the index of the first apparition of 2, and 7 is the index of the first apparition of 14.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but first index of "not 52" will also be 0 (index of 2 which is not 52). Do you want something like first index of a number which is neither of [51, 52] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) returns the first index of each number if you specify `return_index=True`. You can filter the result pretty easily using, e.g., [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
u, i =  np.unique(vec, return_index=True)
result = i[np.isin(u, [51, 52], invert=True)]
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that `u` is a significantly reduced search space compared to the original data. Using `invert=True` also speeds things up a little compared to explicitly negating the resulting mask.

A version of `np.isin` that relies on the fact that the data is already sorted could be made using [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) like this:

```
def isin_sorted(a, i, invert=False):
    ind = np.searchsorted(a, i)
    ind = ind[a[ind.clip(max=a.size)] == i]
    if invert:
        mask = np.ones(a.size, dtype=bool)
        mask[ind] = False
    else:
        mask = np.zeros(a.size, dtype=bool)
        mask[ind] = True
    return mask
```

You could use this version in place of `np.isin`, after calling `np.unique`, which always returns a sorted array. For sufficiently large `vec` and exclusion lists, it will be more efficient:

```
result = i[isin_sorted(u, [51, 52], invert=True)]
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Forgot about the `invert` keyword in `np.isin` +1

Comment: nice answer, I didn't know about the `return_index` parameter. For performance, however, see the comparison in my updated answer. Small loops and lists aren't necessarily slow compared to vectorized methods when the latter require more memory to be allocated.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
vec = np.array([2, 2, 2, 51, 51, 52, 52, 14, 14, 14, 51, 51, 52, 52])

first_occurrence = []
for x in np.unique(vec):
    if x not in [51,52]:
        first_occurrence.append(np.argmax(x==vec))
```

[`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) finds the index of the first occurrence of the maximum (i.e. `True`) in the boolean array `x==vec`. As `x` is from `vec` it is guaranteed that there is minimum one `True` value.

---

Performance depends on the size of `vec` and on how many values to find. This simple loop method (blue) outperforms the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66102553/3944322) (green and orange) for larger arrays, especially for small numbers of values to find like in the example (for the given toy example it's in fact 1.7 times faster) ([source](https://gist.github.com/StefRe/1d73c663d5b162cbda7bb3dd6d838a19)).
[image]
[image]
It turns out the using `unique` with `index=True` is relatively slow, another factor for larger arrays is the memory allocation for the mask.

Comment: Excellent analysis